# Generate a color code from an arbitrary string

Tags: scripting, zsh, colors, prompt

I want my shell prompt to have a different, unique, consistent color automatically based on the hostname of the server.

For example, when I log in to a particular server, the prompt should be a color specific to that server, which will be the same the next time I log in to that server. I don't want to hard code any mapping of server names to colors. It doesn't have to be a beautiful color, but it would be good if it had high contrast with a dark background.

So, perhaps I could create a deterministic hash of the hostname and convert that into a color code usable by the prompt.

How would I do that?

Comment: Is this for any particular shell? Are you dealing with heterogeneous servers (different Unices), or are they all the same?

Comment: It's for zsh. The unixes are Ubuntu, macOS and Debian.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up doing this

```bash
# get hash and byte size
prompt_hash_and_size=`hostname|cksum`
# get hash part and apply modulo 256 to put it in range 1..255
prompt_hashcolor=$(echo $prompt_hash_and_size|awk '{print $1%255 + 1}')
# use it as background color in prompt
PROMPT="%K{${prompt_hashcolor}}%F%~%f%k%  "
```

you can compact it to

```bash
prompt_hashcolor=$(hostname|cksum|awk '{print $1%256}')
```

Comment: That's a random-ish small integer between 0..127. I don't even know how prompt uses that value. How well does it rate for (a) contrast with background, and (b) distinctiveness for different hosts?

Comment: @Paul_Pedant it works pretty well on both accounts

Comment: It's 0...255. I guess it could generate some low contrast results, but I've been lucky so far. Most of that range seem to be ok: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/15/Xterm_256color_chart.svg

Comment: If you're using a heterogeneous set of servers, you may want to use `cksum` rather than the non-standard `md5sum` (unless you know for sure that this GNU utility is installed everywhere). `cksum` returns (space delimited) a decimal checksum and a length.

Comment: @Kusalananda interesting idea. But then I get the problem: how do I reduce the decimal `cksum` hash result to a range of 0-255? I guess I could use modulo.

Comment: Yes, modulo, but do restrict it to 0-254 (254 is the largest allowed color value allowed, according to the `zsh` manual).

Comment: @Kusalananda, that seems to be a bug in the manual. In different sections, it does correctly says the range is 0..255. One can also use RGB specifications with `#xxx` or `#xxxxxx` (see `zsh/nearcolor` for terminals that only support a palette).

Comment: I've updated the code to use `cksum` and `awk` now.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a local network, try using the last octet of the IP address as a base. Maybe rearrange some bits from that, and mix in some 1's or replication to ensure contrast.

You could evaluate the process locally by pulling your hostnames and IPs from /etc/hosts, and tuning the method on your local terminal.

I would recommend doing this in a profile on the remote host. Regenerating it for each prompt would be too costly.

Answer (score 1):

This makes sure to select a color combination that is readable:

[How do I get different colored prompt depending on server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580295/how-do-i-get-different-colored-prompt-depending-on-server)